# List markers disappearing in Chrome and Safari on Float: Left

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I'm trying to achieve the effect of a horizontal list where the markers are squares, each in a different color.  This works in Firefox/Opera:

HTML:

```
<ul id="legend">
    <li id="item1" class="legendMarker"><span class="legendText">Item1</span></li>
    <li id="item2" class="legendMarker"><span class="legendText">Item2</span></li>
    <li id="item3" class="legendMarker"><span class="legendText">Item3</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#legend {
    list-style-type: square;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.legendMarker{
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
}
#item1 {
    color: #65E17B;
}
#item2 {
    color: #66A1D2;
}
#item3 {
    color: #007F16;
}
.legendText {
    color: black;
    padding-right: 35px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

But in both Safari and Chrome, the square markers disappear and I can't figure out why.  I know that the best way to achieve this effect is probably using background images instead of HTML markers, but I'd like to know why this isn't working.  I should note that in Chrome and Safari, the markers reappear if I get rid of `float: left`.  Anyone?

Comment: Seems to work okay to me: http://jsfiddle.net/mUxA3/

Comment: @ExplosionPills, try it using some test files on your desktop--it doesn't work in Chrome/Safari, only Firefox/Opera.  If I had to guess I'd say jsfiddle is rendering using its own engine that does what Firefox (and not Chrome/Safari) does.

Comment: I could see list markers in chrome and Firefox. Try out applying margin to list.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following styles, it should work on all browser:

```
#legend {
    list-style-type: square;
}
.legendMarker{
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-left: 35px;
}
#item1 {
    color: #65E17B;
}
#item2 {
    color: #66A1D2;
}
#item3 {
    color: #007F16;
}
.legendText {
    color: black;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

You don't need to add padding right to each text, you just need spacing between the `li` item, so add margin-left to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately I tested it and it doesn't work in Chrome/Safari.  All it did was move everything to the right.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you don't have a DOCTYPE declaration for your page.